# Redirecting Razor page in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a Razor page public class DoStuffModel : PageModel in my Pages folder. I want mydomain/do_stuff to hit my page.

I have tried adding this to startup

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "do_stuff",
        pattern: "do_stuff",
        defaults: new { page = "/DoStuff" });
```

and a few other things. This can't be that hard. I have it working as do_stuffModel, but that is a terrible name.

Comment: Sorry, Your question is not very clear, Do you want all the url of pages should under the rule of `/mydomain/{pagename}` or just this page should be `mydomain/do_stuff `

Answer (score 1):

For this first add this service in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

Next add this middleware

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Now you can use `Razor Page` but if you want to add path before it you can add folder in pages folder like this `mydomain/newfolder/mypages`